# How can I get the count for the data with same values in a column

Tags: laravel

Assume I have a table and a column name completed , let's say I have a total of 10 , and 4 is completed and has a value of 1 and the rest 6 has a value of 0 which is not completed , how I get to total count of the completed value in a Laravel app please

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    $total_num = DB::table('your_table_name')->where('your_status_column_name','=',1)->count();
```

Simple count(); will do the simple trick

Answer (score 1):

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
                 ->where('status', '<>', 1)
                 ->groupBy('status')
                 ->get();
```

you can get total from it

Answer (score 1):

with raw SQL

```
$count = DB::select("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table WHERE completed = 1")[0]->count
```